# Img как транспортировщик данных

Tags: изображения, javascript, php

Интересная такая штука, на сервер можно отправить данные, например, вот так:

javascript:

```
var i = new Image();
i.src = "handler.php?value=2";
document.body.appendChild(i);
```

На сервере обработчик получит данные и даже отправит. Но как же их извлечь эти данные-то?

handler.php:

```
if (isset($_GET['value'])){
  echo value*2;
}
```

Получается, сервер отправил какие-то данные - число "4".
Так вот, как можно средствами javascript извлечь эти полученные данные для обработки? Возможно ли это?

Comment: Наверное, можно эту картинку вставить в `<canvas>` и оттуда вытащить `ImageData.data`. Но это не поможет обойти CORS, если вы об этом. )

Comment: @Sergiks,я делаю проект без php и ajax Поэтому и вопрос такой. А что такое этот ваш КОРС - понятия не имею

Comment: @Deus, выглядит, как велосипед для ajax'а как раз. А CORS – политика безопасности браузеров, запрещающая, в частности, скрипту что-то делать с данными, полученными с другого домена. Т.е. "картинку" ту же, не со своего домена, никак не разобрать на байты.

Comment: @Sergiks, странный комментарий, картинка с моего домена. Зачем мне другой домен?

Comment: Непонятно: зачем загружать данные в `<img>`, если можно тем же ajax'ом их запросить и получить?

Comment: @Sergiks, элементарно, Ватсон! Штука такая. Ладно, я уже создал объект на iframe, который отправляет и получает данные. Интересно мне просто без "фишек" создать полноценную вещицу. Через пару дней закончу. Покажу обязательно!